# angularjs stop at last item ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an app with AngularJS.
Inside this app I would like to have 2 buttons on each row, except when the total buttons are not even.
How can I let the code stop creating the last col?

With the next code the 6th button (on a array with 5 items) is empty. I don't want this one on the screen.

```
<div ng-repeat="tool in tools">
  <div class="row" ng-if="$even">
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="tool in [tools[$index],tools[$index + 1]]">
      <button class="button button-block button-{{tool.color}}">
        <i class="icon {{tool.icon}}"></i>
        <br>{{tool.name}}
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The use of `ng-if` to pre-empt rows and `$index` to build new arrays should be a clue that your data isn't structured right;  This isn't a very efficient solution.  Instead of trying to manipulate the `ng-repeats`, you should consider re-structuring the data from the controller.

Comment: You could use $last reference inside the ng-repeat, which is true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.

Comment: don't know if it helps, but the keyword `$last` seems to be better no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the inner ng-repeat to use `limitTo` filter;

```
<div ng-repeat="tool in tools">
  <div class="row" ng-if="$even">
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="tool in tools | limitTo:2:$index">
      <button class="button button-block button-{{tool.color}}">
        <i class="icon {{tool.icon}}"></i>
        <br>{{tool.name}}
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer: 
This did the job:
<div ng-repeat="tool in tools">
  <div class="row" ng-if="$even">
    <div class="col" ng-repeat="tool in tools | limitTo:2:$index">